# i created 2 classes and i want to use Class A in the methode of class B

Tags: java

i created 2 classes and i want to use Class A in the methode of class B
     created class A
    i use protected because i created a superclass in my code, dont mind it

```
public class A {
protected String modulname; 
        protected String verantwortliche;
        protected int sws;
        protected int credits;

        public A ( String modulname, String verantwortliche, int sws, int credits ){//beginning of the methode of class A
            this.modulname =modulname;
            this.verantwortliche = verantwortliche;
            this.sws= sws;
            this.credits = credits;
        }
        public class B {
        private String pruefer;
        private double leistungeninprozent;
        //i want to use the Attributes/Constructors form class A in the class B
        //an put it like this:
        public B (class A, String pruefer, double
            leistungeninprozent){ 
                this.leistungeninprozent = leistungeninprozent;
                this.modul = modul;
                this.pruefer = pruefer;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
public B (class A, String pruefer, double
        leistungeninprozent){ 
            this.leistungeninprozent = leistungeninprozent;
            this.modul = modul;
            this.pruefer = pruefer;
    }
```

to this:

```
public B (A aObject, String pruefer, double  //change "class A" to "A aObject"
        leistungeninprozent){ 
            this.leistungeninprozent = leistungeninprozent;
            this.modul = modul;
            this.pruefer = pruefer;
    }
```

then you can access it in the B constructor like this: `aObject.modulname`

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful it worked. And how do I implement the toString methode?
I mean implement the toString of class A into the toString of class b.

Thats the toString form class A:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Module [Modulname=" + modulname + ", Verantwortliche=" + verantwortliche + ", SWS=" + sws
                + ", Credits=" + credits + "]";
    }
```

That is the toString methode from class B:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Leistungen [Pruefer=" + pruefer + ", LeistungeninProzent=" + leistungeninprozent
                + "]";
    }
```

Now i want to make only one toString methode from the two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

At this very early point in the process of learning Java, I would advise avoiding the use of nested classes. An instance of B can only exist within an instance of class A.

To answer your question, a parameter should represent an instance of a class, not the class itself. Which then becomes a local variable within the method, and through which you can access its fields and methods.